# Form open on last position closed

Tags: c#, winforms, position, load

I'm trying to have my form start in the same position it was when it last closed.

I've tried setting the 'Start Position' property on the form to 'Manual' and moving/closing/relaunching the application, but I don't see the effect it had.

If set to 'Manual', is there a way to configure it to load on the last position? (It wouldn't be fixed as it could vary)

Other info that might be of help:

-I have multimonitors

-The form does not have a parent

-C# WinForms

-Visual Studio C# 2010 Express

Comment: Any code to show?  Posting requirements and expecting code is a bit naughty

Comment: There should be a `form.Top` and `form.Left` properties. Store those somewhere when the form closes. Then when the form opens again, set those properties from wherever you stored them.

Answer (score 4):

In the "Properties" window of your form go to "Application Settings". Under "Property Binding" choose and add a new "Location" application setting, name it and save it.
Then go to "Events" and add the "FormClosed" event for your form. To save your  form's last position call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` from this event.

If my instructions were not clear enough, try this (and read the second to last comment): https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/preserve-size-and-location-of-windows-forms-part-i/

Comment: Great solution!